# How to reopen pull request in GitHub?

Tags: git, github

I had created one pull request. on which reviewer asked me to do some changes. I have done those and again committed but by mistake i deleted same branch remotely on my git now thats pull request is closed is there is any way i can reopen that?

I have everything on my local.

Comment: Can you push the branch again?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk I have pushed but it will make a new pull request .